# Amortized analysis (accounting/banker's method) for tree operations

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Suppose we have a tree data structure with root $r$ with two operations:

Add($x, y$) - adds the node $y$ as a child to the node $x$

Zip($x$)- this makes the node $x$ and all of $x$'s ancenstors direct children of the root. So if we had a tree like $r \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$ then Zip($3$) would make a new tree with root $r$ and children $1, 2, 3$ and $4$ as a child of $3$.

Say Add has cost $1$ and Zip($x$) has cost = length of path from root to $x$

We want to see that the amortized cost of a sequence of Adds and Zips is $\leq 2$ per operation. We want to use the banker's/accountant method to do this.

I'm a bit lost here and would appreciate the help.

Comment: "We want to use the banker's/accountant method to do this."  Please include a description of this method, as applied to a simple problem.  I have never heard of it before.

Comment: Also, worth noting: $\mathrm{Zip}$ is _idempotent_, in the sense that $\mathrm{Zip}(\mathrm{Zip}(T))=\mathrm{Zip}(T)$.  So each node might as well get zipped once... _hint, hint_.